# scoreboard - add score to the main score board - not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a score to the current score, so when we are printing the output i want the earlier score to be added to +1 and then sum it up and print the new score. This do not work, i have tried many options, how could i solve this problemset? The output i get is 1 and the same output i showing after the first result.

```
namespace scoreboard
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public double regnut()
        {
            int score = 0;
            return score = score + 1;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string input = textBox1.Text;

            int score;
            count();




        }
        void count()
        {
            string iny = textBox1.Text;
            double score = 0;

            if (iny == "t")
            {
                score = score + 1;
                listBox1.Items.Add(score);
            }
            label1.Text = "Score: " + score;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are always initializing `score` back to zero. You need to have a variable which holds the current value of your `score`. Example as below:

```
private int currentScore = 0; // holds you current Score value

void count()
{
    string iny = textBox1.Text;
    int score = currentScore; // sets initial value based from the current Score
    if (iny == "t")
    {
        score = score + 1; // increment value
        listBox1.Items.Add(score);
    }

    currentScore = score; // store the value in the variable
    label1.Text = "Score: " + currentScore.ToString();
}
```